google/apiclient Google_Client compatibility errors with php8 : Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError:count() / Deprecated: Return type of Google_Model
Having run composer require google/apiclient (which resulted in Using version ^2.0 for google/apiclient), I am using Google_Client to manage my sign-in using php8 but I get compatibility errors for different versions of php:

php8.0 I get Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given in C:\wamp64\www\.....\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 67
php8.1.13 & 8.2.0 I get Deprecated: Return type of Google_Model::offsetExists($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\wamp64\www\....\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Model.php on line 249

google/apiclient claims to be "PHP7.4 or higher" but obviously is running into these issues once a $_POST['credential'] is detected.
I am running this from a wamp localhost on a Windows 11 PC while in dev.
What do I need to do to get googleapi login to work?
index.php:
<html lang="en">
<body>
<?php
require_once 'class.GoogleLogin.php';
$google=new GoogleLogin();
$google->handleGooglePosts();
echo $google->getGoogleScriptInclude();

and
class.GoogleLogin.php:
<?php
require_once 'class.config.php';

class GoogleLogin {

    public function getGoogleScriptInclude() {
        return "<script src='https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client' async defer></script>";
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function getGoogleLoginTags() {
        $redirect=config::google_redirectUri;

        return "
                <div id='g_id_onload'
                    data-client_id='".config::google_clientId."'
                    data-login_uri='$redirect'
                    data-auto_prompt='false'>
                </div>
                <div class='g_id_signin'
                    data-type='standard'
                    data-size='large'
                    data-theme='outline'
                    data-text='sign_in_with'
                    data-shape='rectangular'
                    data-logo_alignment='left'>
                </div>
            ";
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Final public function handleGooglePosts() {
        $site=config::siteURL;
        $redirect=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if ( isset($_POST['credential'])) {
            $id_token = $_POST['credential'];

            require_once 'autoload.php';
            $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => config::google_clientId]);

            if ( !$client ) {
                echo "<LI>No client";exit;
            }

            $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,),));
            $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);

            try {
                $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "<LI>Exception ".$e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
            .
            .
            exit;


Well... talking to bard - it suggested I deleted my composer.lock file and re-issued the composer require google/apiclient. This seems to be working now (I think)
